# Division of side opposite trisected angle in a triangle.

Tags: geometry

Angle A of triangle ABC is trisected  making three segments $ a/2-x, x+y, a/2-y $ on opposite side $a$. How to find $x,y?$

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Don't expect this type of question from a 16k user.

Comment: @Arnaldo Sandwiched between them we have in order $ b,p,q, c$ four cevians. Now $b/q =$ known, $ p/c =$ known in terms of $x,y$ as they are bisectors. One more condition is to be incorporated, and got stuck there. Stewart's thm helps?

Comment: How does "a/2-x", "x+y", "a/2-y"  describe the three segments?  Are they arbitrary names you gave them like, "tom" "dick" and "harry"?  Are the lengths of the segments and a and x and y can be any numbers what's so ever and you picked them just because the equations were true?  Or is there some geometric meaning to the symbols?  What does "on opposite side a" mean?  Three out of four of those seem to be words but it doesn't seem to be a clause in any way.

Comment: They could be described using any symbols, however should add up to $a=$ the side opposite to angle $A$. I put in compensating $x,y$ just to compare with $a/2.$Nothing sacrosanct. We could also take them like: $a/3-p, a/3-q, a/3 +p+q $ etc, as well.Two unknown should be embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can use bissection theorem for $\Delta ABE$:

$$\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{AE}{DE}\to \frac{AB}{\frac{a}{2}-x}=\frac{AE}{x+y}\to AB=\left(\frac{\frac{a}{2}-x}{x+y}\right)AE$$

and for $\Delta ADC$

$$\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{AC}{CE}\to \frac{AD}{x+y}=\frac{AC}{\frac{a}{2}-y}\to AC=\left(\frac{\frac{a}{2}-y}{x+y}\right)AD$$

Now by Stewart in $\Delta ABC$ and cevian $AD$:

$$\frac{AB^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}-x\right)a}-\frac{AD^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}-x\right)\left(\frac{a}{2}+x\right)}+\frac{AC^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}+x\right)a}=1$$

By Stewart in $\Delta ABC$ and cevian $AE$:

$$\frac{AB^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}+y\right)a}-\frac{AE^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}+y\right)\left(\frac{a}{2}-y\right)}+\frac{AC^2}{\left(\frac{a}{2}-y\right)a}=1$$

Can you finish?

Comment: OK, thanks, shall finish it up.